# DistinctCount is counting space in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When I run my expression, I get 6 inside of 5 as the expression is counting space. Can anyone please help to amend my expression

=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!EnrolmentAtRiskStatus.Value ="No Risk", Fields!RefNo.Value,""))

Answer (score 0):

CountDistinct counts non null values. An empty string is not null.

try the following

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!EnrolmentAtRiskStatus.Value ="No Risk", Fields!RefNo.Value,nothing))
```